# Installing ruamel.yaml.clib with docker

Tags: python, django, docker, ruamel.yaml

I have a small project in django rest framework and I want to dockerize it. In my `requirements.txt` file there is a package called `ruamel.yaml.clib==0.2.6`. While downloading all other requirements is successfull, there is a problem when it tries to download this package.

```
#11 208.5 Collecting ruamel.yaml.clib==0.2.6
#11 208.7   Downloading ruamel.yaml.clib-0.2.6.tar.gz (180 kB)
#11 217.8     ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
#11 217.8      command: /usr/local/bin/python -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-b8oectgw/ruamel-yaml-clib_517e9b3f18a94ebea71ec88fbaece43a/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-b8oectgw/ruamel-yaml-clib_517e9b3f18a94ebea71ec88fbaece43a/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-n2gr5j35
#11 217.8          cwd: /tmp/pip-install-b8oectgw/ruamel-yaml-clib_517e9b3f18a94ebea71ec88fbaece43a/
#11 217.8     Complete output (3 lines):
#11 217.8     sys.argv ['/tmp/pip-install-b8oectgw/ruamel-yaml-clib_517e9b3f18a94ebea71ec88fbaece43a/setup.py', 'egg_info', '--egg-base', '/tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-n2gr5j35']
#11 217.8     test compiling /tmp/tmp_ruamel_erx3efla/test_ruamel_yaml.c -> test_ruamel_yaml compile error: /tmp/tmp_ruamel_erx3efla/test_ruamel_yaml.c
#11 217.8     Exception: command 'gcc' failed: No such file or directory
#11 217.8     ----------------------------------------
#11 217.8 WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8b/25/08e5ad2431a028d0723ca5540b3af6a32f58f25e83c6dda4d0fcef7288a3/ruamel.yaml.clib-0.2.6.tar.gz#sha256=4ff604ce439abb20794f05613c374759ce10e3595d1867764dd1ae675b85acbd (from https://pypi.org/simple/ruamel-yaml-clib/) (requires-python:>=3.5). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
#11 217.8 ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ruamel.yaml.clib==0.2.6 (from versions: 0.1.0, 0.1.2, 0.2.0, 0.2.2, 0.2.3, 0.2.4, 0.2.6)
#11 217.8 ERROR: No matching distribution found for ruamel.yaml.clib==0.2.6
```

---

However, there is no problem when I download this package without docker. Any suggestions?

Here is Dockerfile:

```
    FROM python:3-alpine

    # set work directory
    WORKDIR /usr/src/app

    # set environment variables
    ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
    ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

    # install dependencies

    RUN pip install -U pip setuptools wheel ruamel.yaml ruamel.yaml.clib==0.2.6
    COPY ./requirements.txt .
    RUN pip install --default-timeout=100 -r requirements.txt

    # copy project
    COPY . .
```

Here is compose file

```
    version: '3.8'
  
    services: 
      web:
        build: .
        command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
        volumes:
          - .:/usr/src/app
        ports: 
          - 8000:8000
        env_file: 
          - ./.env.dev
```

**EDIT**

As mentioned in comments by @Anthon, the problem was related to alpine. I used `python:3.9-slim-buster` instead in Dockerfile and problem solved!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is with the way your `Dockerfile` tries to install `ruamel.yaml.clib`. It should be installed using pip (just as documented for the `ruamel.yaml`).

I suggest you take it out of the requirements.txt and explicitly do a

```
 pip install -U pip setuptools wheel ruamel.yaml.clib==0.2.6
```

in your `Dockerfile` instead. This should just get you the pre-compiled wheel instead of trying to compile `ruamel.yaml.clib` from source, which will not work if you don't have a C compiler installed (this is actually what docker complains about)

I have ruamel.yaml.clib running succesfully in multiple Docker containers (but I never use a `requirements.txt`)

Comment: Thank you for answer. I tried to install it in Dockerfile, but still the same error occurs. Should I have C compiler in any case? Currently I dont have

Comment: Can you post your Dockerfile? Which architecture is the container build upon? Yes a C compiler helps and would probably solve the problem, but it is unclear to me why the pre-compiled wheels are not taken.

Comment: I edited question and added Dockerfile and compose file

Comment: Standard wheels for Linux don't work on Alpine, that is why it is trying to build from source. Have you tried starting from a Debian or Ubuntu container. Have a look at [Using Alpine can make Python Docker builds 50× slower](https://pythonspeed.com/articles/alpine-docker-python/)

Comment: This solved my problem. I tried 3.9-slim-buster and everything worked successfully. Thank you so much

Answer (score 15):

I see that OP has moved on from Alpine to solve this issue, but for whatever reason you need/want/wish to stay on Alpine, you can install `gcc`, `musl-dev`, and `python3-dev`:

```
⋮
RUN apk add --no-cache gcc musl-dev python3-dev
⋮
RUN pip install ruamel.yaml.clib …
```

Comment: Another approach is to use the pre-built [py3-ruamel.yaml apk](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/community/x86/py3-ruamel.yaml). Add `py3-ruamel.yaml` to your `apk --no-cache add`. You can leave the dependency in requirements.txt if it makes things easier -- if the apk is already installed, pip will say "requirement already satisfied" and continue.

Comment: Thank you. This worked in my home assistant OS container. Now I am able to install hass-cli (homeassistant-cli)[https://github.com/home-assistant-ecosystem/home-assistant-cli]